# 'unresolved reference Error' 'from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am creating an application that shall interact with websites, the important code is listed below. So when it comes to importing 'ChromeDriverManager' from 'webdriver_manager.chrome' I get the Error "unresolved reference 'webdriver_manager'" and "unresolved reference'ChromeDriverManager'". The problem is that I want to autoupdate the chromedriver and this was the solution I came up with but it won't work when running it in pycharm but when I run it from the console it would work...does anyone have a solution on this because I prefer to test out my code in pycharm than starting it from the console every time.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager # important for chromedriver-autoinstall
import time
p= ChromeDriverManager()
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging", "enable-automation"])
# disables 'Browser is managed by test software' and surpresses error with USB device
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=p.install(), options=chrome_options)
# see above + install right version of chromedriver
t = 2  # time to wait for input of number
i = 1  # current round
duration = 1
```

Comment: did you install the webdriver_manager under your project venv ?

Comment: No I didn't and I also can not find it under external libraries and when I enter into the terminal:  `py -m pip show webdriver-manager` the output is:` WARNING: Package(s) not found: webdriver-manager` even tho it gives me the message `requirement already satisfied...` when I try to install it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue, as the package didn`t show up in the interpreter. I ended up just installing the webdriver-manager manually via settings.

[Package installation interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9Hu6.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer, especially, the image that you have attached, helped me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In `selenium` `4.10.0`, the driver manager is now included and out of beta, so you probably don't need to use ChromeDriverManager at all:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging", "enable-automation"])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```